# How can a crew be warned of "Clear Air Turbulence" during the flight?

Tags: safety, weather, equipment

Is there any piece of equipment, on board, to assist the crew to identify and avoid clear air turbulence (CAT)?

Comment: Ahh. The holy grail. Following a huge amount of research over the years, LIDAR seems to be the most promising. See this [article from Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/boeing-jaxa-turbulence-lidar-laser/). Realistically, the best piece of equipment today is the VHF comm radio where the poor guy flying through it reports it to ATC and it gets passed to you.

Comment: Not in terms of sensor equipment. Weather charts obtained prior too flight identify areas of possible CAT. Usually, this data is not accurate enough to make changes to planned altitude/route prior to flight, but at least it increases awareness of what to expect. In flight, pilot reports from other aircraft, relayed by ATC, aid in selecting/changing altitude to an altitude where no turbulence, or less turbulence is expected.

Comment: I think there are experiments with airborne lidar goig on (e.g. [DELICAT](https://hal-onera.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01111380/document)), else Lidar is used from the ground as CAT contains no water vapor, thus is not detectable using radar wavelengths. See: [How does radar detect turbulence and wind speed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23402/3201)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do pilots foresee turbulence?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/how-do-pilots-foresee-turbulence)

Comment: I have asked about CAT, not turbulence.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open on the grounds that CAT isn't addressed much in the other question (and one of the answers that does address it isn't accurate.)

Comment: @eduardoguilherme The T in CAT stands for "Turbulence." You said so yourself in your question...

Answer (score 2):

Not on board the aircraft as of yet, no (unless, as @Gerry said, you count the radio that lets you hear about the person ahead of you running into CAT).

There *are* ways of detecting CAT, however, which could become standard aircraft equipment in the future.  [LIDAR is one possibility](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27140350), as both @Gerry and @mins mentioned; see also [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01111380/document) and [here](https://www.wired.com/story/boeing-jaxa-turbulence-lidar-laser/).  Interestingly, the idea of using LIDAR to detect clear-air turbulence has been around [since at least the late 60s](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4899-5615-6_20), but, when it was first proposed, they couldn't get the sensitivity high enough; later, when this obstacle was overcome, they faced a different problem, which was that the equipment required was far too heavy, bulky, and power-hungry to be practical, which remained the case until very recently.  [N-slit interferometry](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2040-8978/12/1/015705/meta) can also be used to detect clear-air turbulence (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3PMbDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT416&lpg=PT416&dq=n-slit+interferometry+clear+air+turbulence&source=bl&ots=GHTICv4biY&sig=fdK8JU8MMHpPc47nm_pXttBYWJE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjey9eO2rLaAhVE4YMKHQJMAmUQ6AEITTAE#v=onepage&q=n-slit%20interferometry%20clear%20air%20turbulence&f=false), for instance), and [an interferometric (I think; the patent description is remarkable in its unintelligibility) CAT detector was patented in 1978](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4195931A/en), but the equipment required is far too large to fit on an aircraft; as a result, most work with interferometric CAT detection seems to have been in the area of developing a ground-based clear-air turbulence detector that could monitor runway approaches for dangerous CAT.